# Page with Directory Browsing enabled does not return file list, only 404 File not Found

Tags: iis-7, kentico, directory-browsing

I am trying to turn on Directory Browsing for a specific folder in my website, but no matter what I do the page always returns a 404 Page not Found.

Running IIS7 with a Kentico CMS7 site.

The folder location is www.sample.com/Public/FolderIWant

I can successfully access files within the FolderIWant, so an incorrect url is not the problem.

I have enabled Directory Browsing via IIS7 UI for the FolderIWant and disabled the Default Document feature along with deleting the default documents listed there.
I have also enabled Directory Browsing on the Public folder as well with no luck.

Everything I have read online so far says that this is all that should have to be done to get Directory Browsing working for a folder.

Any help getting this to work would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the folder in the Kentico content tree, or within the physical codebase?

Comment: @probrandono - the folder is within the physical codebase

Comment: Are you using MVC or WebForms version of Kentico?

Comment: @BenEG - I am using the WebForms version of Kentico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the "/Public/FolderIWant" directory into Kentico excluded URLs. It's done in CMS Site manager -> Settings -> select site -> URLs and SEO -> Excluded URLs. Otherwise the URL is treated as part of CMS content which is not found.